# ortools not found in nix-shell

Tags: or-tools, nix, nixos, nix-shell

Starting a nix-shell as follows

```
nix-shell -p python39Packages.ipython python39Packages.ortools --run ipython
```

Followed by

```
 import ortools
```

results in

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0c521df57bb5> in <module>
----> 1 import ortools

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ortools'
```

Any advice on how to approach this appreciated!

Comment: - Is the package you are searching for available in the nixpkgs ? - you can check here https://search.nixos.org/packages
- are you using the correct version of nixpkgs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually the case if nix does not symlink the Python packages (the `site-packages`). Here, you need to combine the required Python packages using this command:

```sh
nix-shell -p "python39.withPackages(ps: with ps; [ipython ortools])" --run ipython
```

Then, you will be able to easily import ortools. Spawning a shell like that has the added bonus that it usually makes the command easier to read.